# mysql query how to use if condition?

Tags: php, sql

i want to use `If condition` inside `MySQL` query is this possible ?

I've googled how to use if statement inside sql query i found hard tutorials can any one give me simple example ?

Comment: Never did that before...for sure there is a simpler way to reach your goal. Can you provide us an example? So we can give you a better solution

Comment: Do you mean SQL if statement or PHP's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside mysql query add this

```
SELECT * ,  IF(usergroup=5, 1, 0) AS banned FROM mytable
```

or

```
  SELECT  IF( viewers > 100 , 1, 0) AS hotproduct FROM mytable
```

the condition is like this

```
IF ( condition here , true , false )
```

hope this help

Comment: That's wrong. Should be:

SELECT IF(useridgroup=5, 1, 0) AS banned FROM mytable

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CASE statement:

```sql
CASE WHEN col1 = 'A' THEN 'something'
  WHEN col1 = 'B' THEN 'something else'
  ELSE 'Even something else'
END
```

This is possible to do in SELECT clause, WHERE clause, ORDER BY, etc.

Answer (score 0):

An example for IF statement:

```
SELECT IF(age < 15, 'child', 'teenager') AS age_description FROM table_users
```